# Can I sign .exe files using .spc and .pem files?

Tags: jar, certificate, ssl-certificate, exe, code-signing

What are the steps to sign a .exe file?

I already have a PKCS #7 Certificate (.spc file*), because I've used it to sign .jar files
*but it was requested using the keytool with a .csr file as follows http://help.godaddy.com/article/4780

The specific question is:
How do I sign .exe files? and if this .spc file works or I need a new one?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have a .pvk file, just the .spc and the .pem (used to request the .spc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [OpenSSL](http://www.openssl.org/) and [signtool.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

1. [Combine the certificate and private key files into a PFX file](https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html).
2. [Use the signtool.exe to sign your code](http://help.godaddy.com/article/4778).